# Нужно ли использовать Modernizr

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Раньше при верстке сайта я использовал  `Modernizr`  для поддержки  старых версией браузеров . Последное время заметил глюки. Сайт неработал  в старых браузерах. Можете подсказать  какие варианты есть  без использования `Modernizr`. Можно сделать  так .
И есть такая роблема с Flexbox float несовместим .Для этого есть решения

```
    <div class="parent FlexContainer BorderBox BlockContainer">

      <div class="child FlexContainer BlockContainer TextAlignCenter "><h1>Child</h1></div>
      <div class="child FlexContainer BlockContainer TextAlignCenter "><h1>Child</h1></div>
      <div class="child FlexContainer BlockContainer TextAlignCenter "><h1>Child</h1></div>
      <div class="child FlexContainer BlockContainer TextAlignCenter "><h1>Child</h1></div>

            </div>

<style type="text/css">
.parent{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}

.FlexCountainer{
   display:flex;
   flex-flow:row wrap;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
}

.BorderBox{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}

.BlockContainer{
 display:block;
}

.child{
   width:20em;
   padding:5em 1em 5em 1em;
   margin:0.2em;
}

.TextAlignCenter{
  text-align:center;
  }



</style>
```

Comment: Modernizr - не палочка выручалочка. Оно все-лишь определяет что умеет браузер. Если вам по каким-то причинам нужна поддержка старых браузеров не умеющих в flexbox, то для них нужно писать отдельные стили.

Comment: Сасибо за ответ  есть для этого  какие  инструменты .Особенно  мне нужно подрежка   safafri  -5.1.

Comment: Safari 5.1 поддерживает flex, просто расставьте `-webkit` префиксы

Comment: например  flex-flow   неподерживается   и с префиксом  -webkit-box.

Comment: `display:-webkit-box;`  `display:-webkit-flex;` `display:flex;` `-webkit-box-direction:normal;` `-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;`  `-webkit-flex-flow:row wrap; ` Поддержка  Safari +5.1

Answer (score 0):

Нашел оптимальный вариант .Вот

```
<style type="text/css">
.parent{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}

.FlexCountainer{
   display:flex !important;
   flex-flow:row wrap !important;
   align-items:center !important;
   justify-content:center !important;
}

.BorderBox{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}

.BlockContainer{
 display:block;
}

.child{
   width:20em;
   padding:5em 1em 5em 1em;
   margin:0.2em;
   float:left;
}

.TextAlignCenter{
  text-align:center;
  }



</style>
```